# How to duplicate modifier on same object?

Tags: modifiers

I am using lattice modifier on an object and I just want to duplicate the modifier on the object its already applied. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a *Copy* button near the top of any modifier:

[image]

Comment: It would be have been very clear if the button was named "duplicate". Thanks

Comment: It is a bit inconsistent with the rest of the UI.. One of those little oddities :/